# php regex for multiple lines with tabs and caps to csv string

Tags: php, regex, file, csv

I have several text files in the format

```
CATEGORYA[can be multiple words but all caps] 
[tab]Item11[multiple upper/lower case words with spaces&numbers],$3.99
[tab]Item12,$7.49[the prices sometimes don't have the $]
etc.
[new line]
CATEGORYB[can be multiple words but all caps] 
[tab]Item21,$3.99
[tab]Item22,$7.49
etc.
```

I would like to convert it to a csv file in the format

```
 CATEGORYA,Item11,$3.99
 CATEGORYA,Item12,$7.49
 etc.
 CATEGORYB,Item21,$3.99
 CATEGORYB,Item22,$7.49
 etc.
```

this is the code i started with

```
//import file
$file = file_get_contents('./20051019.txt', true);
//split each category into an array
$catarray = preg_split("[regex of somesort]", $file);
//get number array elements
$numcats=count($catarray)
for ($x = 0; $x < $numcats; $x++)
{
//split the category from the elements
//loop through the elements replacing the tab with the category and a comma
//add element to a string
}
//write string out to a file
```

Can someone please help with the regex or know a better way to do this?

Comment: You have already the regex, you wrote 'several upper/lower case words with space and numbers'. That, as a regex, is expressed by `(\w+\s+)*\w+`. You just need to learn the language (http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Here we answer questions when one is stuck, we don't solve the problem in their stead.

Comment: I'm assuming when you put `[new line]` that there are actually two new lines in a row (i.e. you have one line with content, one without content, and one with content). If that's the case, split on two new lines in a row, then for each of those "categories" split again by new line. Then just loop through everything.

Comment: $catarray = preg_split("/[\n\n]/", $file); doesn't work

Comment: Try `preg_split("/(\n\n|\r\r|\r\n\r\n)/gm", $file)`

Comment: Warning: preg_split(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's not necessary. Get rid of the `g` then.

Answer (score 0):

```
//import file
$file = file_get_contents('./20051019.txt', true);
//split each category into an array
$catarray = preg_split("/(\n\n|\r\r|\r\n\r\n)/m", $file);
//get number array elements
$numcats=count($catarray)
//output string
$csvstring="";
for ($x = 0; $x < $numcats; $x++)
{
    $curline=$catarray[$x];
    $elements= preg_split("/[\n\t]/", $curline);
    $numitems= count($elements);
    $cat =trim($elements[0]);
    for ($y = 1; $y < $numitems; $y++)
    {
      $csvstring=$csvstring.$cat.",".trim($elements[$y])."\n";
    }
}
//write string out to a file
```